# Ajax сохранение содержимого дива

Tags: php, html, ajax, tinymce

Всем привет.
Никак не могу понять в чем проблема.

Есть див который содержит текст описания новости.

```
<div id="my_html_content">Содержимое с <b>HTML</b> тегами и всем что может быть&nbsp;еще.</div>
```

Прикрутил к этому диву tinymce с возможностью inline вывода редактора и сохранением.
В общем, при сохранении в редакторе, вызывается save_onsavecallback, которая в свою очередь вызывает мою функцию ajax_save_news в которой аргументом идет содержимое дива получаемое с помощью

```
tinymce.get("my_html_content").getContent()
```

Собственно функция которая делает посыл

```
function ajax_save_news(news_content)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax_action.php?action=ajax_save_news&news_id="+NEWS_ID,
        type:"post",
        dataType:"html",
        data:"news_content=" + news_content,
        success:function(return_data)
        {
            alert(return_data);
        }
    });
}
```

Все бы хорошо, только вот в результате у меня режет html.
В консоли данные еще целые, а вот при принте в php уже ломаное содержимое.

Я не могу понять в чем проблема. Выходит так, что спотыкается на неразрывных пробелах и тому подобному в содержимом.
Пробовал всякие манипуляции с функциями экранирования, но видимо не то.

**UPD:** 
Пример текста который отправляю из дива (это уже с html содержимым который в редакторе в админке)

```
<p>Премьер-министр Израиля Биньямин Нетаньяху <br />поручил МИД подготовить выход страны из ЮНЕСКО. <br />Как сообщает&nbsp;Haaretz со ссылкой на пресс-службу <br />премьера, Нетаньяху приветствовал решение США <br />выйти из ЮНЕСКО, отметив, что Вашингтон поступил <br />смело.</p>
```

А при получение через $_POST у меня только

```
Премьер-министр Израиля Биньямин Нетаньяху поручил МИД подготовить выход страны из ЮНЕСКО. Как сообщает
```

Comment: "при принте в php уже ломаное содержимое"  как это? Покажите PHP код.

Comment: @E_p добавил пример текста. В PHP ничего нет по сути, только print. Тут я не правильно посылаю сами данные видимо. Только не могу понять что не так.

Comment: Проверьте **post_max_size**  в php.ini

Comment: Вы в dev tools (chrome/firefox/ie...) посмотрели что конкретно уходит серверу?

Comment: а что значит получение через $_POST? где кусочек кода, который выводит в див обратно при получении из аякса?

Comment: Я так понял нужно просто в html вытягиваете через .html() Потому как .getContent() даст конечный результат и его и отправляет ajax

Comment: @E_p к сожалению, дело не в этом. данные сохраняются и большего обьема, но там из форм, а тут данные из дива.

Comment: @Jean-Claude в див ничего обратно не выводит. Там прямое редактирование. Содержимое дива меняется и обновление не требуется

Comment: @E_p в консоли выводит правильное содержимое и на вкладке network и Form data тоже правильные данные вроде.

Comment: К серверу или от сервера?

Comment: @E_p к серверу.

Comment: Тогда показывайте код `ajax_action.php`

Comment: @E_p в php части все нрмально. Тут дело в том, что нужно было использовать encodeURIComponent для news_content, а полученные данные уже обработать urldecode. Спасибо за участие и помощь!!!